# How do I take all button in a line Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

This is full code and returning buttons but not in a row,

```
FutureBuilder <List<Symptoms>>(
                    future: futureData,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('Checked');
                        List<Symptoms> data =  snapshot.data!;
                        print(data);
                          print(data.length);
                        return 
                        
                       Container(
                        height: 500,
                        width: 100,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: data.length-2,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              print(data[index].title);
                              return Container(
                                width: 300,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text(data[index].title))
                              );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        print('Checked2');
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                      }
                      // By default show a loading spinner.
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    },
                  ),
```

If I use Row Element then Result :
This shows many errors. I am trying to solve but I can't

```
A vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#82804 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
```

How could I?
I am new to flutter.
Thanks

Comment: What's your expected UI? Have you tried setting `scrollDirection` property of `ListView`?

Comment: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#05494 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
This Error is coming

Comment: ListView(
              scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
                children : <Widget>[
                  FutureBuilder <List<Symptoms>>(
                    future: futureData,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('Checked');
                        List<Symptoms> data =  snapshot.data!;
                        print(data);
                          print(data.length);
                        return 
                        
                        ListView.builder(

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView.builder` widget needs a height. Probably you did not specify its height.
You can do so by wraping your `ListView.builder` widget with a `Container` widget and give a height to `Container`.

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  child: ListView.builder(
     itemCount: data.length-2,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        print(data[index].title);
        return Container(
           width: 300,
           color: Colors.white,
           child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text(data[index].title))
        );
     },
  ),
)
```

Or

You could also wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` widget to occupy all space available from the parent widget.

Note: The parent of `Expanded` widget should have height and/or width defined or else it will show you and error

Comment: The Buttons are not coming in a row

Comment: If you want them in row then change the axis of listview to `Axis.horizontal` by using `scrollDirection` property of `ListView.builder`. Also, if possible include a photo of what you are trying to implement or what you have done so far, so that people understand better

Answer (score 0):

```
    Container(
                        height: 500,
                        width: 100,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: data.length+2,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              print(data[index].title);
return(index ==0 )

                              ? Container(
                                width: 300,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text(data[index].title))
                              );
                          },
                        ),
                      ):
Container()
```

note if you want to access the items in a the row you have to -2 in the index
like this

```
Container(
                                    width: 300,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text(data[index-2].title))
                                  );
                              },
                            ),
                          )
```

with that you suppose to understand the idea, i would have given you a sample code from my project i am not with the system.

Comment: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..12: -2

Comment: if you have 10 items in the lis, then you add 2 you to it, you provide the two items. that means you will use (index==0)?......: (index==1)?container(): what you want to show